# Python3, Selenium4 how to open a new 'TAB' from particular node?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In Selenuim4 I have an input node that do a POST request when you click on it.

By default, it change the current window.

I prefer to open a new TAB to process this page and latter, return to main page to avoid

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException:
Message: stale element reference: stale element not found
```

I searched tons of examples, but they are for old Selenium.

Moreover, seems like there's a new TAB feature.

From: [Java selenium-4-new-window-tab-screenshots](https://blog.testproject.io/2020/06/30/selenium-4-new-window-tab-screenshots/)

```
WebDriver newTab = driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
```

How can I do it in Python with a particular node?

Retrieve product**s** input element**s**

```
products = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//input[@attr="foobar"]')
    for product in products:
        # FIXME need new tab opened to retrieve one product
        product("new window").click() # this is wrong, but you know what I mean
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to give a solution without more context. For instance, do you have an example of the web page you're trying to use?

Comment: Figured it out, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, figured out the way:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
[...]

windows_category = driver.current_window_handle
products = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//input[@attr="foobar"]')
for product in products:
    action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
    action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(product).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()

    # Switch to the new tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

    # close TAB
    driver.close()

    # Code for this tab [...]

    # Switch to category (parent) window
    driver.switch_to.window(windows_category)
```